# Border bottom is missing for some items in Activity tab in Firefox

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page, firefox

The border bottom is missing in the Activity tab's sub tabs (favorites, bounties, reputation, responses) those have numbers in it, when tracking the next privilege.

But the border bottom  issue is not exists when tracking a tag badge. The issue occurs in Firefox browser.

**Screenshot for reference:**

> [image: Bottom bar]

**GIF for the same:**

> [image: Bottom bar missing]

OS: Windows 10 Pro
Firefox: 60.0.2
Zoom: 100%

Comment: Sorry, even with the gif I don't understand what is missing.

Comment: Oh, that's border, not "bar" or "margin". By "bar" thought you meant the whole line with all items. So this is very minor design issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The border bottom issue in the Firefox browser, when tracking the *Next privilege* has been fixed recently.

Screenshot for reference:

> [image: Border bottom issue has been fixed]