# Unread reputation change breaks design of the activity page

Tags: bug, design, reputation-history, activity

I have an "unread" reputation change on the activity tab of my profile. This breaks the border below the tabs.

[image]

Browser: FF 68.3.0 ESR
OS: macOS 10.14.6
100% zoom

**Edit:**
When changing from tracking a tag-badge into tracking my next privilege the issue disappears, only to re-appear when the selection is reversed. Opposite to this, now fixed, report: [Border bottom is missing for some items in Activity tab in Firefox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/311298/312043)

Comment: Related [Border bottom is missing for some items in Activity tab in Firefox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/311298/312043).

Comment: Curious @Arulkumar, I am tracking the next tag-badge in this case.

Comment: @Arulkumar see update in question.

Answer (score 1):

This is something I can fix by doctering with the CSS of this page using the FF developer tools:

**Original settings:**
[image]

**Altered settings:**(Increased bottom padding from 0.3 to 0.4)
[image]